# Is it possible to use a nested factory in an association (within a trait) with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations, factory-bot

For example, let's say I have an `Address` with nested factories and belongs_to a `Zip`, and an `Order` that has one `Address` and a trait that ideally would create an association to one of the nested factories:

```
  # File one with its own FactoryGirl.define do...
  factory :zip do
  end

  # File two
  factory :address do
    zip  # an address belongs_to a zip

    factory :address_variant do
    end
  end

  # File 3
  factory :order do
    trait :with_address_variant do
       address_variant  # EDIT: this was my bug :)
    end
  end
```

I'd like to use it like so: `FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:order, :with_address_variant)`. But I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'address_variant='` when running the tests.

If I use `FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:address_variant)` in the trait as suggested below, I get a `find': Factory not registered: zipcode (ArgumentError)` when rspec tries to initialize everything.

Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

I rushed my original answer. I think this is the proper way to accomplish what you want:

```
factory :address do
  attribute "1"
end

factory :address_variant, :parent => :address do
  attribute "2"
end

factory :order do
  trait :with_address_variant do
     association :address, :factory => :address_variant
  end
end
```

===

Try this:

```
trait :with_address_variant do
   FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:address_variant)
end
```

Comment: Aha, that does appear to work, thanks. Although oddly enough, if my `address_variant` factory (or the base `address` factory) pulls in another association, I get errors saying that factory is not registered. Odd...I'll accept your answer if there's no better solution, although for now I'm just creating the association in my `with_address_variant` using `association :address, ...` directly, instead of  using a nested factory as shorthand.

Comment: @qix why not edit your question and add all the code that's involved? It'll be easier to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Great, that did it, thanks! And reads more consistently with the rest of the factory definitions. :)